# Security group for Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load

I have some issue with my ELB.
We are develop some web app and we need to close public access to our app from internet. So about test environment:

example.com -> Application load balancer with route53 -> EC2 in private subnet.

In security group for testing i have opened 0.0.0.0/0 for 80 and 443 (port doesn't matter). My app response and everything works fine.

But i don't need 0.0.0.0/0, so i have changed it to my office IP.
And my app stop working, because IP from Load balancer in 2 availability zones are not allowed in security group of load balancer. It's very strange.. This IP is not static and i have no guaranties that this IP don't change in 5 min. So, what we have, I ALB doesn't allow his traffic via his IP?

Answer (score 0):

The EC2 instances do not need to be in the same security group as the load balancer. The load balancer should be in a security group that permits ports 80/443 from the Internet (or your office IP).  The EC2 instances should be in a security group that permits traffic from the load balancer’s security group.

Comment: I understand that. I have the same what you describe. Issue not in security group. Imagine, request go to load balancer via DNS route53. ALB sent traffic to my ec2. in my ec2 2 application with authorization and signin. Request goes successfully to sign. And then i have issue. Traffic that goes back to ELB goes with ELB IP, not via DNS. My ELB in 2 AZ. And that IP not allowed in security group.

Comment: In 2 words. Load balancer can't take himself traffic from IP in availability zone. If i add IPs of ELB, everything works fine

Comment: How do you know this?  Do you have VPC flow logs to prove it?  I have never seen such behavior. If that’s really the case, you can add the ALB security group to itself.

Comment: Hm, the reason was that NAT IP with IPs ELB cant access to ALB. Added IP ELB and NAT gateway to secutiry group. Fixed. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the reason was that NAT IP with IPs ELB cant access to ALB. Added IP ELB and NAT gateway to secutiry group. Fixed. Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want your application to be open to the public Internet, you can [set up a VPN in your VPC](https://hackernoon.com/using-a-vpn-server-to-connect-to-your-aws-vpc-for-just-the-cost-of-an-ec2-nano-instance-3c81269c71c2) or you can use [SSH port forwarding](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/ssh-tunneling-with-aws-private-subnet/) to access your application in the private subnet. The linked articles are just examples - there are many ways to do it - but both are common approaches. If you choose either of these options, your ALB does not need to be in a public subnet. It can also be in a private subnet since your application doesn't need to be publicly accessible.

These are the most secure and robust options available to you. Alternatively, if you can determine the IP address range which your ISP assigns, you could open a wider network in your ALB security group but still not allow the full internet. E.g. if your ISP always assigns an address in the range of `1.2.3.0-254`, you could add a rule to allow `1.2.3.0/24`. Of course anyone else using your ISP that is assigned one of these addresses would also be able to access your application. Alternatively, you could develop a script that keeps updating your ALB security group with a new dynamic address.

Comment: I have the OpenVPN in my VPC. I can use all resources in my VPC via VPN. But when in security group allow acces only for VPN - it doesn't work. Because request goes to Balancer -> ec2, ec2 give answer and requests goes back to load balancer with IP, not with DNS name. There are IP's load balancer. Load balancer can't access his traffic via IP.. Do you understand what i mean?
I use inspect in chrome and take this IP. Or just pong Load balancer or dig it. This 2 IP's added in security group. But it not static